# Overlay heatmap on 1D data like ECG signal

Tags: matplotlib, visualization, heatmap, sign

I have an ECG signal with shape (1, 5000), like this

[image]

and a contribution map with shape (1, 5000), which has values ranging between 0,1.

I want to plot this contribution map as a heatmap on the ECG signal. Currently, I use `plt.pcolormesh(contribution)` and plot like this

[image]

But how can I overlay a heatmap more beautifully like this plot?

[image]

Comment: Interesting question. Can you provide the ECG/contribution dataset to play with? Also how did you obtained the desired result? (Seems like you already have the code, so where are you stuck?)

Comment: @mozway I want to get a plot like the below image, not just like the middle image.
Now I just create a heatmap by `plt.pcolormesh(contribution)` and plot the ECG signal on it by `plt.plot(ecg)`, very simple

Comment: For sake of readability, I would plot them into subplots with `sharex=True`. And isn't the second plot not simply `plt.scatter(x=time, y=ECG_signal, c=contribution_map`?